# What is the different between *&aPtr and &*aPtr?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to know what is the  different between `*&aPtr` and `&*aPtr` if replaced          * & and & *   ?

```
int a;   
int *aptr;  
a = 7;     
aptr=&a;

cout << &* aPtr<< *&aPtr<< endl;
```

Comment: In this particular case: none. Both are equal to `aPtr`.

Comment: Seems like a simple question, but there are subtleties to it. +1.

Answer (score 7):

They have the same value, but `*&aPtr` is an lvalue that refers to `aPtr` whereas `&*aPtr` is a prvalue that has the same value as `aPtr`.

Answer (score 3):

If the types are primitives (integers, characters, booleans etc.), then they will yield the same value.

A difference may occure if the operators `&` and `*` are overloaded for specific class. in this case, depending on the implementation alone - there might be a difference.

One other thing: a corner case can occure if `T* t` actually points to null:

```
int* i = nullptr;
*&i; //ok, first takes the address of i, then dereference it, yielding a null pointer again
&*i //wrong, dereference a null pointer, yielding undefined behavior
```

Comment: Smart pointers will override `operator*`. I've even seen `operator&` overridden too. This is very important to point out.

Comment: I think it's pointed, unless I don't understand you correctly (I'm not pretending to cover every example)

Comment: The comment wasn't for you, it was for others reading your answer - yes you made the point. Consider if you used `std::shared_ptr<int>` instead of `int*`, `*&` would yield a reference to the `std::shared_ptr<int>` while `&*` would yield `int*`.

Comment: I forgot to comment on your other piece of brilliance. The undefined behavior you mention is real; a modern compiler, seeing `&*i`, can assume that `i` will *never* be a null pointer and completely remove an `if(i==nullptr)` test from your code as part of its optimizations. This kind of thing has actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

These unary operators & and * group right to left.

So in this expression

```
&*aPtr
```

at first operator `*` is applied and you get lvalue of `a` after that operator `&` is applied and you get rvalue of pointer to `a`. 
Its value is the same as the initial value of `aPtr`. However you may not write for example

```
&*aPtr = &a;
```

while you may write

```
aPtr = &a;
```

In this expression

```
*&aPtr
```

at first operator `&` is applied that yields the address of variable `aPtr` itself. After that operator `*` is applied and you get again `aPtr`.

The difference between this expression and the above expression is that you may write

```
*&aPtr = &a;
```

because expression *&aPtr yields lvalue of `aPtr`.